# How to clone only type properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose i have the code:

```
type SimpleState = 
{
   a1: string
// little more properties
}

type ComplexState = 
SimpleState
& {
b1: numeric,
c1: boolean
// many other properties
}

const workingState :ComplexState = // all properties initialozation

const stateParam :SimpleState = workingState;

cacheSimpleState(stateParam)
```

In runtime cacheSimpleState receive ComplexState object with all properties. Is there a way to clone workingState to stateParam so it only have SimpleState properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, not. Typescript can't check the interface members on runtime.

An option, although not very fancy, is to manually list the props:

```js
function cacheSimpleState<T extends SimpleState>(data: T): SimpleState {
    return {
        a1: data.a1
    }
}
```

This way, if `SimpleState` needs more data, at least your build will know.
You need to be careful, though, if the optional parameters appear.
An option would be:

```js
type SimpleState = 
{
   a1: string;
   b1?: string;
}
const defaultSimpleState: SimpleState = { // All the mandatory props
    a1: ''
}
const defaultOptionalState: SimpleState = { // All the optional props
    ...defaultSimpleState,
    b1: ''
}

function cacheSimpleState<T extends SimpleState>(data: T): SimpleState {
    let props: Partial<SimpleState> = {};
    for (let prop in data) {
        if (prop in defaultSimpleState || prop in defaultOptionalState) {
            props = {...props, [prop]: data[prop]};
        }
    }
    return props as SimpleState;
}
```

Comment: The functions don’t need to use a generic T since they aren’t using any of the additional properties of T and since any T which extends SimpleState is assignable to SimpleState.  It can just be a function which takes SimpleState and returns SimpleState. (Though I can see the advantage of using “extends” from a readability perspective).

Comment: I put the generic T since I want to ensure that any mandatory property in `SimpleState` will be in `data`, with the correct type

Comment: Isn’t that true for `function cacheSimpleState(data: SimpleState): SimpleState` as well?

Comment: I think you would face the index problem in that case. I did a test and had `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'SimpleState'` error

Comment: Huh.  You're right but that's really weird!  I don't understand why the type for `prop` in `for (let prop in data)` is `Extract<keyof T, string>` for `T` and not just `string` while it's `string` for `SimpleState`.  Well I guess I learned something new today.